# Ubuntu boot stuck with after installing amd gpu pro graphics drivers showing no gui

Tags: dual-boot, gui, amd-graphics, boot-repair, amdgpu-pro

Hello I downloaded AMD gpu pro for graphics, installed it and entered `sudo reboot`.

After the reboot the Ubuntu 18.04 boot stuck at showing ok ok ok...

The message, where the boot sequence apparently got stuck:

```
Started disk manager.ice----r systemd-networkd crashed before the ppp link was shut down
```

And gui is also not loading.

Can any one help how to resolve this error[image: this is the screen i got]

Answer (score 0):

Please do check if you've downloaded the correct driver. It should be for Ubuntu 18.04 and not for 20.04. Secondly, try to load Ubuntu in a recovery mode. To boot Ubuntu in recovery mode you either have to hold the shift key or press escape key. It will show you a black screen with option from there choose "Ubuntu Advance Option/Ubuntu Recovery mode". Then you've select start Ubuntu to launch Ubuntu with minimal driver setup. After login try the following command.

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Then edit the below line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

To:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash amdgpu.dc=0"
```

Then press "ctrl+x" and then press "Y".

sudo update-grub

```
Then reboot.
```